# Installing an OTF Font under Ubuntu Server

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, ubuntu-server, otf

I have an OTF Font I want to use with ImageMagick.

Last time I had to install it on other machines, I copied it into /usr/share/fonts and ran `fc-cache`, then, `convert -list font | grep "myfont"` found it.

This time it doesn't find it (even by looking at the font list by hand, without `grep`).

How must the font be chmodded?

Any other clues?

Comment: It's **/usr** /share/fonts.

Comment: sorry that's not the point... in the terminal I wrote `/usr` - it is just a local mistake in this online-text. BTW: this typo is now fixed.